# If an invalid input is entered, when it attempts to re-ask the input it seems to auto answer it with the previous answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code uses a lot of inputs, and to ensure replay-ability I have used functions to replay the code if they provide an invalid input. However if the user enters an invalid input, and the function runs, it seems to auto answer the input with the previous input.
(I apologize if this question is framed poorly, I am new to coding)

Here is the code:

```
# Importing the random module
import random
import time
# Take the playstyle input from the user
print("Rock, Paper, Scissors! - By Max Pearson")

try:
    def code():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        playstyle = int(input("Would you like to play RPS, or simulate a number of games? (1,2): "))
        if playstyle == 1:
            def rps1():
                # Take the users input of RPS
                user_choice = input("What is your choice? Rock, Paper, or Scissors?: ")
                # Strips and lowers user input
                user_choice = user_choice.lower()
                user_choice = user_choice.strip()
                RPS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
                computer_names = ["Computer", "Robot", "Android", "A.I", "PC", "Algorithm", "Laptop", "Alexa", "Windows"]
                computer_name = random.choice(computer_names)
                # Selecting the computer's choice
                computer_choice = random.choice(RPS)
                computer_choice = computer_choice.lower()
                computer_choice = computer_choice.strip()
                # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Rock
                if user_choice == "rock":
                    print("You have chosen Rock")
                    print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
                    if user_choice == computer_choice:
                        print("It's a tie!")
                    elif computer_choice == "paper":
                        print("You lose...")
                    else:
                        print("You win!")
                # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Paper
                elif user_choice == "paper":
                    print("You have chosen Paper")
                    print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
                    if user_choice == computer_choice:
                        print("It's a tie!")
                    elif computer_choice == "rock":
                        print("You win!")
                    else:
                        print("You lose...")
                # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Scissors
                elif user_choice == "scissors":
                    print("You have chosen Scissors")
                    print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
                    if user_choice == computer_choice:
                        print("It's a tie!")
                    elif computer_choice == "rock":
                        print("You lose...")
                    else:
                        print("You win!")
                # Fallback for an invalid input
                else:
                    print("Please enter a valid choice")
                    rps1()

                def newround():
                    playagain = input("Would you like to play again?(Yes/No): ")
                    playagain = playagain.strip()
                    playagain = playagain.lower()
                    if playagain == "yes":
                        rps1()
                    elif playagain == "no":
                        print("Okay!")
                    else:
                        print("Please enter a valid input(Yes/No)")
                        newround()

                newround()

            rps1()
        # Checks if the user wants to simulate games
        elif playstyle == 2:
            def rps2():
                def percentage(x):
                    x = (x / num_sims) * 100
                    return x

                RPS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
                results = []
                try:
                    # Takes an input from the user, to define the number of games
                    num_sims = int(input("Please enter the number of simulated games you would like: "))

                    # Loops for the number the user entered

                    if num_sims > 0:
                        for i in range(0, num_sims):
                            choice1 = random.choice(RPS)
                            choice2 = random.choice(RPS)
                            # Runs a check on every possible choice and adds the result to a list
                            if choice1 == choice2:
                                results.append("tie")
                            elif choice1 == "Rock" and choice2 == "Paper":
                                results.append("loss")
                            elif choice1 == "Rock" and choice2 == "Scissors":
                                results.append("win")
                            elif choice1 == "Scissors" and choice2 == "Paper":
                                results.append("win")
                            elif choice1 == "Scissors" and choice2 == "Rock":
                                results.append("loss")
                            elif choice1 == "Paper" and choice2 == "Rock":
                                results.append("win")
                            elif choice1 == "Paper" and choice2 == "Scissors":
                                results.append("loss")
                            else:
                                print("Please enter a valid choice")
                        # Count the results and store them in a variable
                        wins = results.count("win")
                        losses = results.count("loss")
                        ties = results.count("tie")
                        # Print the user their results
                        print("Here are the results:\nWins = {}\nLosses = {}\nTies = {}".format(wins, losses, ties))
                        def percentified():
                            percentages = input("Would you like these results in a statistic?: ")
                            percentages = percentages.lower()
                            percentages = percentages.strip()
                            if percentages == "yes":
                                print(
                                    "Here are the percentages to one decimal point:\nWins = {:.1f}%\nLosses = {:.1f}%\nTies = {:.1f}%".format(
                                        percentage(wins), percentage(losses), percentage(ties)))
                            elif percentages == "no":
                                print("Okay, enjoy the results")
                            else:
                                print("Please enter a valid choice (Yes/No)")
                                percentified()
                        percentified()
                    else:
                        print("Please enter a valid number above 0")
                        rps2()
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a valid number")
            rps2()
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid choice (1/2)")
            code()
    code()
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid choice (1/2)")
    code()
```

Comment: Take your function definitions outside of other functions. Define them all at the beginning, using arguments and `return` statements to pass values between them. Then create your logic at the end and call the functions as needed.

Comment: don't define nested functions - it makes code unreadable.